# how to recieve local notification in ios when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uilocalnotification

I am using local notification for alarm system but I am facing some problem while handling local notification, When i clicked on alarm notification (When app is closed) its launches app but the problem is it should go to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function but it's not going inside any of the function in `appDelegate` (I used breakpoints to check).
I'm using story board with navigation controller, I want to open a specific view controller on notification click when app is closed.

but when I'm launching that app normally it's going inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

Please suggest.

Any help would be appreciated.

**main.m**

```
#import "DEMOAppDelegate.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DEMOAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**DEMOAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "DEMOAppDelegate.h"        
@implementation DEMOAppDelegate        
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
    }
    return YES;
}                                   
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application 
{
}
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:notification.alertAction message:notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
@end
```

Comment: @tkanzakic- application:didReceiveLocalNotification called only when the app is already opened (running or in background).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, when your app is not running notification it will not react on notification directly.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will contain information about notification only when user opened your app through this notifcation. If he cancels it and opens your app through dashboard icon you are not gonna see this in this method.

Unfortunatelly if you need to react on all notification that happened from last time the user opened the app, only way is to build your own tracking logic and get all events that were in the past based on time.
Also there is no way to even get a list of notification you scheduled for your app, so usually it is a good idea to build in time-based event logic and use notification on top of it, but all the logic happens on your own time-based code. This way even if user disable notifications your critical logic will work.

When the application is running in background you will get notification through `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification`. You can gather those notifications inside your app, and process them on `applicationDidBecomeActive` if you want to do anything specific inside your application for them after user comes back to the app from background.

Comment: When i clicked on alarm notification (When app is closed) its launches that app but the problem is, it's not going inside any of the function in appDelegate.
but when I normally launching that app its going inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

Comment: thats impossible... :) show your main.m and you delegate class please

Comment: @ Grzegorz Krukowski, Thanks for your answer.