# How to get local notification when app is closed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want notification at 2:00 pm and 6:00 pm even if app is closed.

How to check for particular time at which I want to fire local notification and where should I write that code in my code in iOS?

please suggest me a code in `Objective-C`.

Should I use this method?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

If yes then what should I write in this method for getting notification at particular time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075141/how-to-recieve-local-notification-in-ios-when-app-is-closed - See this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941778/how-to-schedule-a-local-notification-in-ios-10-objective-c

Comment: @sp309, your requirement is `Local Notification`, this is easy to do, this is help <a href="http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/">tutorial</a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339052/ios-local-push-notification   go through this link once. This works fine.

Comment: How can i check condition for check current time and compare with 14:00:00 and 18:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

When app is suspended or in background a delegate method `didReceiveLocalNotification` called and local notification comes inside:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

You need to implement above method in `appdelegate`.

**Please remind `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method only called whenever app getting notification through server called as push notifications or remote notification**

Comment: No actually i want notification from Local.Then which method is useful?

Comment: use `didReceiveLocalNotification`, clearly written above.

Comment: apply this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23748277/4003548 to get constant notifications daily.

Comment: Thank you vaibhav.

Comment: Are you sure didReceiveLocalNotification method called even if app is closed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131657/discussion-between-sp309-and-vaibhav).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method for getting local notification.

You should use `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method for getting push notification.

We must know the below things

**When app is not running or when app is closed state**

> If the app is not frontmost and visible, the system displays

```
the alert

message, 

badges
```

> the app, and plays a sound—whatever is specified in the notification. 
>   If the notification is an alert and the user taps
>   the action button (or, if the device is locked, drags open the action
>   slider), the app is woken up or launched. (If the user taps one of the
>   custom actions you specify using the category property, the app is
>   woken up or launched into the background.) In its
>   **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method, the app delegate
>   can obtain the UILocalNotification object from the launch options
>   dictionary using the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey
>   key. The delegate can inspect the properties of the notification and,
>   if the notification includes custom data in its userInfo dictionary,
>   it can access that data and process it accordingly. On the other hand,
>   **if the local notification only badges the app icon, and the user in
>   response launches the app, the**
>   **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method is called**, but no
>   UILocalNotification object is included in the options dictionary. When
>   the user selects a custom action, the app delegate’s
>   application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:
>   method is called to handle the action.

[Apple API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification?language=objc)

**When Applicaton is Running in Foreground State**

> **If the app is foremost and visible when the system delivers the
>   notification, the app delegate’s
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification:** is called to process the
>   notification. Use the information in the provided UILocalNotification
>   object to decide what action to take. The system does not display any
>   alerts, badge the app’s icon, or play any sounds when the app is
>   already frontmost.

[applicationDidReciveLocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification?language=objc)

Also

[iOS: If app is in background and local notification is arrived; which method will called automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701986/ios-if-app-is-in-background-and-local-notification-is-arrived-which-method-wil)

Comment: i have set alert and in alert message i have store notification which coming from uilocalnotification.now tell me how to fire notification through alert when app is closed?

Comment: If the notification is an alert and the user taps the action button,the app is woken up or launched.In its application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, the app delegate can obtain the UILocalNotification object from the launch options dictionary using the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034074/does-launchoptions-uiapplicationlaunchoptionslocalnotificationkey-contain-nsdi

Comment: but how to set on particular fixed time daily?that is my question.for set on particular time,in which method i have to code and what to check?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941778/how-to-schedule-a-local-notification-in-ios-10-objective-c

Comment: yeah this is code but how to check condition for current time and notification time is same?

Comment: First check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036783/how-to-fire-daily-localnotification-at-specific-time-in-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301621/how-to-schedule-daily-local-push-notification-in-ios-objc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030060/schedule-uilocalnotification-everyday-at-specific-time

Comment: Finlay this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval

Answer (score 0):

[application:didReceiveLocalNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622930-application?language=objc) is now deprecated because the class `UILocalNotification` is deprecated.

Use [UNNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotification?language=objc) instead.